# Несовместимость типов, как вернуть данные, где класс реализовывает интерфейс?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

К закрытом классе, т.е. с модификатором `internal` есть поле закрытое, и открытое, открытое должно вернуть ссылку на закрытое, и все бы ничего, но мне не удается этого сделать, `IntelliSense` говорит о том что оба типа не совместимы.

А точнее не совместим `ReadOnlyDictionary<uint, Season>` и `IReadOnlyDictionary<uint, ISeason>`, в то время как `Season` реализует интерфейс:

```
internal class Season : ISeason
{
    ...
}
```

Но я не могу вернуть данные так:

```
internal ReadOnlyDictionary<uint, Season> InternalSeasons { get; set; }
public IReadOnlyDictionary<uint, ISeason> Seasons => InternalSeasons;
```

Это можно побороть? Может я чего то не учел или забыл о чем-то.

Как решить эту ситуацию?

P.S. Каст типов не подходит, т.к. при попытке каста, будет исключение `InvalidCastException`.

С коллекциями такого нет:

```
internal ReadOnlyCollection<Material> InternalMaterials { get; set; }
public IReadOnlyCollection<IMaterial> Materials => InternalMaterials;
```

Comment: Но как это поможет с `IReadOnlyDictionary`?

Comment: А Material тоже internal? А то может проблема в том, что не переменная, а её тип имеет меньшую видимость.

Comment: Да, все классы закрытые.

Comment: Почему не сделать у internal тоже `ISeason`?

Comment: *С коллекциями такого нет* — в общем случае вы не правы, с `IList<T>`, например, такое не прокатит. Всё потому что `IReadOnlyCollection` объявлен с **out** дженерик-параметром

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я бы сделал, однако так не получиться десериализовать json。

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что не получится десериализовать?

Comment: Ага, ну это уже из-за того, что вы хотите от класса многого. Если у каждого класса будет по одной ответственности, то все будет сильно проще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, т.к. данный вопрос встал из-за того что я не мог нормально сделать десериализацию объектов на основе интерфейсов, мне пришлось прибегнуть к следующему решению, а именно написание своего конвертера *(тот что предлагается в библиотеке с `Generic` параметром мне не подошел)*:

```
internal abstract class JConverter :
    JsonConverter
{
    protected abstract string REQUESTED_TYPE_NAME { get; }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.FullName == REQUESTED_TYPE_NAME;
    }
}

internal class JConverter<TFrom, TTo> :
    JConverter where TTo : TFrom
{
    static JConverter()
    {
        Instance = new JConverter<TFrom, TTo>();
    }

    protected override string REQUESTED_TYPE_NAME => typeof(TFrom).FullName;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type _, object _2, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<TTo>(reader);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public static JConverter Instance { get; }
}
```

```
internal class SeasonConverter :
    JConverter<ISeason, Season>
{ }
```

```
internal class MaterialConverter :
    JConverter<IMaterial, Material>
{ }
```

```
internal class TranslationConverter :
    JConverter<ITranslation, Translation>
{ }
```

Далее при десериализации объекта *(в котором есть вложенные объекты, в которых есть зависимые типы и интерфейсы)*, получаем такую картину:

```
public class Response :
    IResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public string Time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public ulong Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("next_page")]
    public Uri NextPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("prev_page")]
    public Uri PreviousPage { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<IMaterial> Materials { get; set; }

    internal static IResponse FromJson(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json, Settings);
    }

    internal static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters =
        {
            SeasonConverter.Instance,
            TranslationConverter.Instance,
            MaterialConverter.Instance
        }
    };
}
```

С таким подходом все интерфейсы в которых указаны только интерфейсы, нормально десериализуются, и более нет необходимости игры с `Generic`'ами.

Comment: можно было [проще](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147504/2881286)

Comment: Можно было, но такие конструкторы писать... У меня там много объектов.